# Meteor Templates not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am still very new to Meteor so I assume I am messing up something really simple.

I am trying to make a super simple hello world with templates and just feed a string into it.

```
## client/body.html ##
<body>
    <div>
        {{> greeter }}
    </div>
</body>

## client/templates/greeter.html ##
<template name="greeter">
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
</template>

## client/greeter.js ##
Template.greeter({ name: "giodamelio" });
```

My output it just

```
<h1>Hello </h1>
```

Why is my template not rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is rendering, but there are three problems: **(1)** change `name` to `myName` or something because it is a reserved word, **(2)** collapse `{{ name }}` into `{{myName}}` (no spaces); and **(3)** the `{{myName}}` will still be blank because your wire-up code is a bit off. Replace what you have in your greeter.js with this:

```
Template.greeter.myName = function() {
   return "giodamelio"
};
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I am still getting the same thing.

Comment: I just took another look...edited my answer. Change `{{ name }}` to just `{{name}}`

Comment: Still nothing. Just a blink space.

Comment: Ugh. `name` is a reserved word! I edited my answer and tested it :)